# How asynctest.TestCase.setUp can be overridden by both async and sync methods?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, asynctest

I am writing a unit test that inherits from `asynctest.TestCase` and would like to create some mixins that perform an [asynchronous `setUp`](http://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctest.case.html#testcases) before each test case:

```
import asynctest

class Mixin1(object):
    async def setUp(self): 
        await super(Mixin1, self).setUp()

class MyTest(Mixin1, asynctest.TestCase):
    async def setUp(self): 
        await super(MyTest, self).setUp()
```

The problem I am seeing is that Mixin1 ends up invoking `asynctest.TestCase.setUp` which happens to be a [non-async method](http://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/unittest/case.html#TestCase.setUp) and we're getting:

```
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Obviously, I can just change `Mixin1` to make a blocking call to `setUp`, but then it would fail if I introduce a second mixin that is async.

I ended up writing all my setUp calls like this, but it feels there must be a better way:

```
async def setUp(self):
    # do stuff
    setUp = super(Mixin1, self).setUp
    if asyncio.iscoroutine():
        await setUp()
    else:
        setUp()
```

Is there a better way to chain the setUp calls?

Answer (score 0):

I would like propose a little fix to your solution which makes it working:

```
async def setUp(self):
    # do stuff
    setUp = super().setUp
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(setUp):
        await setUp()
    else:
        setUp()
```